# Unable to download Google Sketchup with Wine

Tags: software-installation, wine

I am trying to create the blueprint and the virtual image of a robot I am working on. Yet, I am not able to download google sketchup using Wine.

I downloaded Wine using [Documentation Ubuntu Francophone](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/wine) protocol:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install wine1.8
```

And then dowloaded Google Sketchup with a link from the [Documentation Ubuntu Francophone page on GS](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/sketchup) giving "Google SketchUp en français".

Yet, I am not able to find any program folders from wine when trying to do Applications → Wine → Programmes → Google SketchUp 7/8 → Google SketchUp.

[image]

However I downloaded the program `googlesketchupwfr.exe` and tried to install it with wine which seems to be a success as far as if I try to do the same now, it says to me that I am trying to reinstall it.

[image]

**Can you help me installing GS or finding an Ubuntu alternative for my engineering project?** Thanks in advance :p